# Virasoro constraints for parametrized GW invariants

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, string-theory, virasoro-algebra

Gromov-Witten invariants count isolated stable maps from Riemann surfaces to a fixed symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ subject to some incidence conditions. If we instead replace the target manifold with a locally Hamiltonian fibration, we get **parametrized** (or **family**) GW-theory (see [Seidel](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803085), [McDuff-Buse](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110313), [Le-Ono](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3899),...)

It seems obvious that certain properties (e.g., the divisor axiom or WDVV...) extend to this setting. My question is:

1. Is the expectation that the Virasoro conjecture extends to this setting?
2. Are there any problems with extending at least the genus-zero proof of [Liu-Tian](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806028) to this setting?
3. Is there any known case where there is a proof of such a thing for higher genus?